# How to add a handler to embedded-jetty server in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, gwt, embedded-jetty

I am developing with GWT in eclipse, its run ok and launch jetty server like spected, but when i try to communicate my gwt page with php i find jetty server handles php files like text files, just send file contents and does not executes php script.

I need jetty server for GWT code, and run apache/php for php code (in different ports), but jetty must redirect php calls to apache.

Searching in google i find a possible solution: a jetty handler could redirects php request to apache server running php.

Someone knows a better solution?

Someone knows how to add a handler to jetty server running embedded in eclipse?

is there a existing jetty handler what redirects calls (proxy) to another server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need Jetty? Would Apache serving everything work for you?

Comment: Amazing! is too simple, just not launch jetty server, only run apache, and make a alias directory to gwt war folder. Thanks. Instructions here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT

Comment: Jetty can run PHP via its [`FastCGI`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/fastcgi.html) module.